# Running a script within a C# program

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there an easy way (a library) that is available for  evaluating a `.js` (or C# or any scripting language for that matter) expression within a compiled .net C# program that is `PCL` compatible? Or in general, is there a scripting language that one can run within a compiled C# application? Please let me know if you know/have come across something like this.

Here's an example of an expression that I'd like evaluate within a compiled program. 
I will store this in a `.json` file and execute it during runtime:

```
>"$Dir = PB$Dir;$ep = PB$ep;$a = PB$a;if ($dir === 1) { if ($ep < BH$1) { ep = BH$1; a = $a + 0.02; if (a > 0.2) { a = 0.2; } } VY = $VY + a * (ep - $VY); if (VY > BL$2) { if (VY > BL$3) { dir = 0; VY = ep; ep = BL$1; a = 0.02; } } } else {dir = 0;} if ($dir === 0) { if ($ep > BL$1) { ep = BL$1; a = $a + 0.02; if (a > 0.2) { a = 0.2; } } VY = $VY + a * (ep - $VY); if (VY < BH$2) { if (VY < BH$3) { dir = 1; VY = ep; ep = BH$1; a = 0.02; } } }CY=VY;"
```

I will have all the variable values that I will plug in. It needs to be `PCL` compatible so it can be part of a `xamarin` project.

Comment: check [jurassic](https://jurassic.codeplex.com/)

Comment: it is very hard to understand what you want. PCL? do you mean Printer Command Language? if that is true then the commands you have mentioned are not part of PCL. PCL does not support variables.

Comment: @SimpleFellow PCL in this context refers to [Portable Class Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/14/portable-class-library-pcl-now-available-on-all-platforms.aspx)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: @HadiRj I do not think Jurassic (https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic) will work on iOS see: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Jint (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) as JavaScript interpreter for a WinRT Project. It is compatible wit PCL but I heavn't tested it with Xarmin.

Comment: Jint worked out well. I was able to plug in values and evaluate a formula. Went with it since it is available as a PCL which was important to me. Jurassic (thanks HadiRj) also appeared promising and could've worked.